# How to replicate a ddply behavior that uses a custom function with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace all my `plyr` calls with `dplyr`. There are still a few snags and one of them is with the `group_by` function. I imagine it acts the same way as the second `ddply` argument and does a split, apply and combine based on the grouping variables I list. But that doesn't appear to be the case. Here is a rather trivial example.

Let's define a silly function

```
mm <- function(x) return(x[1:5, ])
```

Now we can split the species in the `iris`dataset like so and apply this function to each piece.

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), mm)
```

This works as intended. However, when I try the same with `dplyr`, it doesn't work as expected.

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mm
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As shown in `?do`, you can refer to a group with `.` in your expression. The following will replicate your `ddply` output:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(.[1:5, ])

# Source: local data frame [15 x 5]
# Groups: Species
#
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
# 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 6           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 7           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 8           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 9           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
# 10          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
# 11          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
# 12          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
# 13          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
# 14          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica
# 15          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
```

More generally, to apply a custom function to groups with `dplyr`, you can do something like the following (thanks @docendodiscimus):

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(mm(.))
```

Comment: +1 plus, if the OP wants to use his custom function, he can also do that: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(mm(.))` or just use `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(head(.,5))`

Answer (score 1):

`do()` has been superseded in favour of `reframe()`.

So to do this in the modern up-to-date way, we should use that:

```
reframe(iris, across(everything(), ~ .x[1:5]), .by = Species) # one liner!
```

or using `slice_head()`:

```
slice_head(iris, n = 5, by = Species)
```

Comment: credit: moodymudskipper for the slice_head() idea

Answer (score 0):

`slice` has been created for this :

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(1:5)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  6          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  7          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  8          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>  9          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#> 10          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#> 11          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
#> 12          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
#> 13          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica 
#> 14          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica 
#> 15          6.5         3            5.8         2.2 virginica
```