# How to replace ddply with Dplyr or Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, plyr

I am currently using `ddply` to apply a function I have written to a data frame. The function evaluates each row based on the values in the columns and then applies a number of other functions to the data in that row. The result is a data frame with the same structure as the input data frame and an additional column with the result of the applied function for each row.

My problem is the data set is reasonably large and therefore using `ddply` takes a long time - too long for the purpose!

I have read a number of other SO questions and blog posts on replacements to `ddply` when time is of the importance. Most posts either recommend using data.table or some combination of functions in the `dplyr` package with `do`. While speed is of the most importance, I have never used data.table so ease of use / intuitiveness is also important.

Similarly, while [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133356/how-to-replicate-ddply-behavior-with-dplyr) was very useful in explaining how to use different `dplyr` functions in combination your own function, I also need to pass in other objects to my function, which I am unsure how to do using the answer in the question.

I have created a simplified example below. My question then is how to replicate the below `ddply` function call with either `dplyr` or `data table` given my above points.

First, I set up some data to mimic the structure of the actual data

```
noObs <- 1e5
dataIn <- data.frame(One = rep(c("J", "K"), noObs/2), Two = rep(c("ID", "BR", "LB", "OZ"), noObs/4),
                     Three = runif(noObs))

secondaryData <- data.frame(Two = c("ID", "BR", "LB", "OZ"), Size = c(300, 500, 250, 400))
```

A simplified example of my function is below (in practice, the function parameters are greater than 2 and it calls other functions in itself)

```
MyFunction <- function(dataIn, secondaryData){

  groupNames <- c("BR", "LB")

  if(dataIn$One == "J"){
    if(!(dataIn$Two%in%groupNames)){
      if(dataIn$Two == "ID"){
        idx <- match(dataIn$Two, secondaryData$Two)
        value <- secondaryData[idx, "Size"]
        dataIn$newCalc <- dataIn$Three*value
      }else{
        dataIn$newCalc <- dataIn$Three*1000
      }
    }else{
      idx <- match(dataIn$Two, secondaryData$Two)
      value <- secondaryData[idx, "Size"]
      dataIn$newCalc <- dataIn$Three*value+1
    }
  }else{
    idx <- match(dataIn$Two, secondaryData$Two)
    value <- secondaryData[idx, "Size"]
    dataIn$newCalc <- dataIn$Three*value
  }

  return(dataIn)

}
```

The `ddply` call looked like

```
dataOut <- ddply(dataIn, names(dataIn), MyFunction, secondaryData)
```

Finally, some examples of things I have tried (I am yet to try `data.table`)

```
dataIn %>% group_by(names(dataIn)) %>% do(MyFunction(dataIn, secondaryData))
dataIn %>% group_by(names(dataIn)) %>% MyFunction(dataIn, secondaryData)
dataIn %>% group_by(.dots = names(dataIn)) %>% MyFunction(secondaryData)
```

**EDIT**

I have been able to find a way with `dplyr` that works except it is even slower than with `ddply` and I can't figure out how to use `group_by` with `names`. This doesn't seem right to me as `dplyr` is meant to be faster.

In addition, I have been experimenting with `data.table`, but haven't been able to get it to work. Again, I am looking for something that runs faster than `ddply`

```
#Plyr
start <- proc.time()
dataOut <- ddply(dataIn, names(dataIn), MyFunction, secondaryData)
plyrTime <- proc.time() - start

#Dplyr
#Works
start <- proc.time()
res <- dataIn %>% group_by(One, Two, Three) %>% do(MyFunction(.,secondaryData))
dplyrTime <- proc.time() - start
#Doesn't work
res <- dataIn %>% group_by(.,names(dataIn)) %>% do(MyFunction(.,secondaryData))

#Data.table
dataInDT <- data.table(dataIn)
dataInDT[,.(MyFunction(.,secondaryData)), by=.(One, Two, Three)]
```

Comment: Maybe `library(dplyr); dataIn %>% group_by_(.dots = names(dataIn)) %>% myFunction(projSettings, secondaryData)`. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: SO is not a codewriting service. Show us what you've already tried (including a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)).

Comment: @lukeA I have added a reproducible example. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. What was wrong with the result of `dataIn %>% group_by_(.dots = names(dataIn)) %>% MyFunction(secondaryData)`? I can't see that you tried that.

Comment: @lukeA thank you for the comment. I did try that except it produces a warning. Upon further investigation you can see that the suggested method doesn't properly apply the algorithm, in other words it just takes the first element

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `data.table`. Notably, it performs the correct calculations for each row but at a remarkably faster speed. The format of function is different to adapt to the different style of `data.table`. I'm sure there is an even better or more correct way to solve it using `data.table`, but the below solution works well.

```
dataInDT <- data.table(dataIn)

groupNames <- c("BR", "LB")
start <- proc.time()
dataInDT[, NewCalc := {
  if(One == "J"){
    if(!(Two%in%groupNames)){
      if(Two == "ID"){
        Three*secondaryData[match(Two, secondaryData$Two), "Size"]
      }else{
        Three*1000
      }
    }else{
      Three*secondaryData[match(Two, secondaryData$Two), "Size"]+1
    }
  }else{
    Three*secondaryData[match(Two, secondaryData$Two), "Size"]
  }}, by=.(One, Two, Three)]
datTableTime <- proc.time() - start
```

Comparing this to the old solution and you can see the speed is greatly improved

```
start <- proc.time()
dataOut <- ddply(dataIn, names(dataIn), MyFunction, secondaryData)
plyrTime <- proc.time() - start
```

Of course, in practice the `data.table` function I used was even more intricate, in particular the `by` section was much longer.

I was unable to find a solution using `dplyr` and am still curious to know how it would work.